# GPU (Nvidia) TLB misses

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, tlb

There are plenty of documentation/publications on CUDA/Nvidia GPUs, but I never encountered anything about TLBs.

1. Do GPUs use TLBs similar to CPUs (and, therefore, have TLB hits/misses)?
2. How are TLB misses handled? By CUDA driver or by GPU HW?
3. Are there cases when TLB misses cause significant/noticeable performance impact?

Answer (score 2):

A TLB does exist. I am not aware of any official documentation but its size can be determined via reverse engineering. See for example Zhe Jia et.al.: [Dissecting the NVidia Turing T4 GPU via Microbenchmarking](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1903.07486)

> […] within the available global memory size, there are
> two levels of TLB on the Turing GPUs. The L1 TLB has 2 MiB page entries and
> 32 MiB coverage. The coverage of the L2 TLB is about 8192 MiB, which is the
> same as Volta.