# Understanding the specifics of CUDA virtual memory

Tags: memory-management, cuda, virtual-memory

I am learning CUDA and I am trying to understand how virtual memory works and I was reading the [relevant nvidia documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#virtual-memory-management).

In CPU land the CPU holds some virtual-physical page mappings in the TLB that it consults to resolve physical addresses. On a page fault the OS steps in and updates the TLB based on its page tables. Understanding this process makes it possible to reason about the performance of a big host of programs.

My google-fu may be bad, but I can't understand how this works in a GPU. The article I linked above seems to imply that `cudaMalloc()` invokes the driver on the CPU to allocate the virtual addresses and map them to physical addresses much like a CPU program would do, but it's unclear what happens then. Is there a GPU TLB? If so, is it local to the core, the SM, or is it GPU-wide? What are the synchronization implications of a call to `cudaMalloc()` and/or to a page fault?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a full answer since you seem to want to know what happens on a page-fault. But yes, a TLB exists, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439577/gpu-nvidia-tlb-misses/75439914#75439914

Comment: Thanks! Citadel being more transparent than nvidia is not a great sign...

Comment: In the blog post [Maximizing Unified Memory Performance in CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/maximizing-unified-memory-performance-cuda/) it is mentioned that there are "multiple levels of TLBs" and that for the P100 two SMs share a single TLB. Sadly not even the Pascal Whitepaper mentions that fact. I also did a quick search through the Volta, Turing, Ampere, Ada and Hopper whitepapers. No luck...